# How can I display three months at the same time using FullCalender Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I display three months at the same time using the FullCalender in Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through manual!

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#multiple-calendars